# How to expose auto-generated web reference classes to VBA in a .NET Excel AddIn

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net, web, excel-addins

I am using Visual Basic .NET to build an Excel AddIn that provides client access to a web service.  Visual Basic creates a Reference.vb file from the web service's wsdl, and this vb file contains an interface that has various classes that are used to access the web service.

In this AddIn, I have written and shared some functions via COM to VBA. I would like to share the classes in Reference.vb to VBA as well. As it is, the classes in Reference.vb show up in the VBA Object Browser, but they are all empty.

Visual Basic does not allow me to put

```
<Microsoft.VisualBasic.ComClass()> _
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(True)> _
```

in the `Interface` statement in Reference.vb.  It seems that if I want the classes in Reference.vb to show up "unempty" and usable in the VBA object browser, I have to add

```
'<Microsoft.VisualBasic.ComClass()> _
'<System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(True)> _
```

to every one of the `Partial Public Class` objects in Reference.vb.  This is quite tedious as there are many classes, and especially considering that Reference.vb is auto-generated and replaced every time I update the service reference.  Thus I would have to continually re-edit Reference.vb.

Is there some way to "mass expose" the classes in Reference.vb to VBA in order to use the web service directly from VBA?

I have Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks!